# git stash gives merge error / conflict that is unable to resolve

Tags: git, git-stash

I already have stashed my changes and I can see them when I use `git stash list`. I did `git pull --rebase upstream master` successfully. (It had conflict in FileA, I resolved it.) Now I want to get my latest stashed changes at `stash@{0}:`. So I use `git stash apply 0`. Its gives me message `Merge conflict in .gitignore`. I fixed / merged/ resolved conflict in .gitignore.

Then did `git stash apply 0`, I received same error `Merge conflict in .gitignore`. This time I again fixed .gitignore, and I committed this .gitignore file hoping it would take care. ( I did look up on stakcoverflow and found exact same issue faced by someone and took steps).

Then I again did `git stash apply 0` and same error again in loop. How to get past this error.

After `git stash apply` , I don't see all my changes that are supposed to be applied from the stash. I just get the conflict message for .gitignore but don't see other changes that I would like to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git stash apply` takes the commits that `git stash` made and attempts to apply (merge) them.

This attempt either succeeds, or stops with a merge conflict:

- If it succeeds, Git has done its best to apply the stash.  View the result (however you like) and if you like it, use `git stash drop` to discard the stash commits.
- If it fails, Git has still done its best to apply the stash.  View the result, resolve conflicts, and if you like the end result, use `git stash drop` to discard the stash commits.

In other words, *don't keep re-applying* the difference between the stashed commits and your current, in-progress work.

Comment: After git stash apply , I don't see all my changes that are supposed to be applied from the stash. I just get the conflict message for .gitignore but don't see other changes that I would like to see.

Comment: In that case, you're *not* happy with the results, so don't drop the stash. Look inside the stash to see what's in it: `git stash show` (or `git stash show 0`, same thing, you only need the number when it's not zero). I expect you will see that this stash is not the stash you want; if so, use `git stash list` and `git stash show` on each of the other stashes.